# Upload images on 3D shape by customers

Tags: plugins

I am planning to launch an online store for a product which is a cube based gift. Customers should be able to upload images on a 3D cube (4 sides) shape in the online store and able to customize it. The cube could be rotated by arrows (right, left) These images would appear on the 3D cube after upload. They could upload images from their computer, phone or even Facebook.

Do you think that I should reach out for a developer who only makes me a plugin for Wordpress site or similar to Wordpress? Or should I pay for a whole online store built from scratch?

If you have any questions please ask me and I will try to answer! Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [Gmedia Photo Gallery](https://wordpress.org/plugins/grand-media/) plugin. It allows you to upload and display images in Cubic 3D. You can rotate the cube left, right, up and down. Take a look at the [demo](https://codeasily.com/portfolio/gmedia-gallery-modules/cubik-3d-photo-gallery-for-wordpress/).